# ModuleNotFoundError for module 'linearmodels'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, regression, linearmodels

I want to perform an OLS Panel Regression

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

from linearmodels.datasets import wage_panel
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS

data = wage_panel.load()
```

But I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fe79e40655e1> in <module>
      3 import statsmodels.api as sm
      4 
----> 5 from linearmodels.datasets import wage_panel
      6 from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
      7 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linearmodels'
```

I have no idea why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Type `help("modules")` into your IDLE, see if you get the module `linearmodels`, this ensures you have successfully installed it.

Comment: I get the same error. It seems like `linearmodels` hast to be installed separately

Comment: thank you! that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"linearmodels" is a separate package, see https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels. Therefore, it must be installed separately:

`pip install linearmodels` works for me.